# Uncaught Error Error: ENXIO: no such device or address, open '/dev/tty'

Tags: javascript, tty

How to solve the problem of "Uncaught Error Error: ENXIO: no such device or address, open '/dev/tty'"?

I run the following code in Visual Studio Code but it returns an error about /dev/tty.

How to solve it?

My code:

SkillsBuild.js

```
const prompt = require("prompt-sync")();
var name1 = prompt("Enter your first name");
var name2 = prompt("Enter your second name");
console.log("Your full name is ", name1 , name2);
```

Reuslt:

```
/usr/bin/node ./SkillsBuild.js
Process exited with code 1
Uncaught Error Error: ENXIO: no such device or address, open '/dev/tty'
    at openSync (fs:592:3)
    at prompt (/home/frankie/node_modules/prompt-sync/index.js:67:10)
    at <anonymous> (/home/frankie/Desktop/JS/SkillsBuild.js:3:13)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader:1255:14)
    at Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader:1309:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader:1113:32)
    at Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader:960:12)
    at executeUserEntryPoint (internal/modules/run_main:83:12)
    at <anonymous> (internal/main/run_main_module:23:47)
```